# How do import directive in testModule in Angular 2.0

Tags: unit-testing, angular

I am trying like this

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({    
               declarations: [MyDirectiveName]
      });
```

But it's not working, I am getting error, Cannot create instance of component as it's not imported in TestModule

Is there something like this ?

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   directives :[MyDirectiveName]
  })
```

Comment: Are you trying to create the directive in the test using `TestBed.createComponent(Directive)`?

Comment: yes @peeskillet

Answer (score 0):

Trying the create the directive with `TestBed.createComponent(Directive)` isn't going to work. That method is just for component creation. What I normally just do is create a dummy test component, and add the directive to that component's template. This is also the recommended way in [the documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#attribute-directive)

```
@Component({
  template: '<div your-directive></div>'
})
class TestComponent {}

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [YourDirective, TestComponent]
});

fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
```